# best way to switch html content by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you please advice me How I can switch html content by javascript?

for example:

```
if($sid == 0)
 {one html code}
else
 {another html code 2}
```

LESS, jQuery, CSS3, etc - which way is better?

Comment: You haven’t specified criteria for goodness, or what you mean by switching html content, and the pseudocode makes little sense (looks like HTML would be embedded directly in JavaScript – can’t do that).

Answer (score 3):

You should use jQuery `load` and pass the `HTML` content back, for example:

```
if($sid == 0) {
  $('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
     alert('Load was performed. (sid equals 0');
  });
} else {
  $('#result').load('ajax/othercontent.html', function() {
     alert('Load was performed. (sid is not equal to 0');
  });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is designed to do what you've asked (and much more obviously) in a non-browser specific fashion.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    if(somecondition) $('#div1').show();
     else $('#div2').show();
  }); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1" class="hidden">...</div>
  <div id="div2" class="hidden">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what

```
if($sid == 0)
```

is supose to be, but if you want to change the html content you can use

```
$("#id").html("<span>your html</span>");
```